# My slider images are not showing in mobile browser but they are showing in desktop

Tags: html, css

```
.slide-4 {
    background: url("images/slider2/10.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99999;
}
.slide-5 {
    background: url("images/slider2/12.jpeg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99999;
}
```

This is my css code , They were  showing up in mobile browsers but now not showing in mobile browsers and also all the images size is less then 1mb , maximum image size is 804kb ,

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether the div has 'height: auto' style in the media query. Background image for an element without content will work only if it has a fixed height.

Comment: there is no height style in div